# How do I safely put casement window back in from inside on top floor

Tags: windows

We removed double-glazed wooden casement window (2 windows with a central bar) from top floor of house yesterday to paint and the frame a different colour. We thought we would do a better job this way instead of trying to paint from inside especially as we were changing the colour. The house backs onto a river and is too high up anyway to access from the outside.

My concern is putting it back in, because when we removed it was heavier than expected. Im worried Im going to struggle to hold it in place whilst my wife screws in the screws (although thankfully we do have new screws and electric screwdriver). Any tips/ideas on how I can do this safetly and prevent it dropping if I do slip.

Is there a safe way to do this to minimize the risk of dropping it.

Comment: Wait, you took the whole window unit out instead of just the window panes? Pics please.

Comment: thew window frame is still in place but the window within their wooden are the bits taken out, i.e each window is attached to the frame on one side via two hinges, each hinge reuires three screws to attach window back to frame, make sense ?

Comment: Never mind, I attached a bungie rope from window to central window pillar, and one round myself attached to door to give a bit (probably false) sense of security and it wasnt too bad, done :)